# MongoDB java driver latest version(4.1.0) not available in maven repo

Tags: mongodb, maven, mongodb-java, maven-dependency

The latest mongo db driver version is not available in maven rep. Is it usual or expected.

Mongo DB driver Release notes: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases
Maven repo URL: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver

Comment: I think you might want to read through this https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/

Comment: That helps. It has the required info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/getting-started/installation/).

For Legacy Driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For Sync Driver:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So, mongo-java-driver and mongodb-driver-legacy are same ?

Comment: No. You will get legacy classes e.g., com.mongodb.DBCollection, and com.mongodb.DBCursor in Legacy driver unlike Sync driver. More you can find in the link provided.

Comment: I see the latest supported version is 3.12.9 at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/.  Didn't you have an error with during compiling?

Comment: Thanks that helped to resolve a problem that I was on weeks